# child element <i> tag not retain <xsl:value-of> xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

How to retain `<i>` in my output. My XML code is:

```
<root> 
  <Title><i>Apple</i>: 70</Title> <Title><i>Banana</i>:
40</Title> <Title><i>Sweet</i>: 150</Title> <Title><i>Drinks</i>:
40</Title> 
</root>
```

And my XSLT template is:

```
<xsl:template match="Title"> <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,': ',':
$')"/> </xsl:template>
```

Convert:

```
        <root> <Title>Apple: $70</Title> <Title>Banana: $40</Title>
        <Title>Sweet: $150</Title> <Title>Drinks: $40</Title> </root>
```

```
    Required:
```

```
        <root> <Title><i>Apple</i>: $70</Title>
        <Title><i>Banana</i>: $40</Title> <Title><i>Sweet</i>: $150</Title>
        <Title><i>Drinks</i>: $40</Title> </root>
```

Please advise how to solve

Comment: Please post a [mcve] not snippets of code taken out of context.

Answer (score 0):

Change your template to

```
<xsl:template match="Title/text()[contains(.,':')]">
  <xsl:value-of select="replace(normalize-space(.),':\s',': \$')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The output should be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <Title>
      <i>Apple</i>: $70</Title>
   <Title>
      <i>Banana</i>: $40</Title>
   <Title>
      <i>Sweet</i>: $150</Title>
   <Title>
      <i>Drinks</i>: $40</Title>
</root>
```

Of course, you should combine this template with the *identity template*.

Comment: It is not working for me. I have <i> tag or <b> tag or <i> & <b> or no formatting in my input. Please advice

Comment: If this is not working, the only alternative is editing your post to include a [mcve] as already demanded in the other comment above.